# Django UUIDField vs Timeflake as primary key

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, uuid

I have an API written using Django Rest Framework and I'm using Postgres as my DB. I'm looking to convert my primary key to a more obscured format as I do expose them in external URLs. In my research, I came across this package called [Timeflake](https://github.com/anthonynsimon/timeflake) and I couldn't find much out there on people's experiences with it and Django and how it compares to using a UUIDField with uuid4.

In Timeflakes README, it says that uuid4 isn't suitable for clustered indexes and can cause performance degradation. As I understand it, Postgres indexes are heap-based and therefore wouldn't suffer from fragmentation like a clustered index if one used a uuid4 primary key. Aside from that are there any other reasons that someone might choose to use Timeflake primary keys over a uuid4 if they are using Postgres and their primary goal is it keep performance high and also have obscured ids in their URLs?

Also, I did want to mention that I'm aware of the pattern of adding an external_id to your models and using that for external communication and the auto-incrementing pk for internal use. I certainly see the merits of this approach but my app is already pretty large and if using either Timeflake or uuid4 causes minimal performance hits I'm ok with that since it feels like the simpler and cleaner approach.

**EDIT** Based on a comment I'm adding my app's typical query patterns. ~90% CRUD operations the remaining queries are more complex and combine joins and subqueries to create some more complex views. Those queries are critical and I don't want them to slow down.

Comment: Performance is a pretty wide subject, it might be useful to folks if you describe how your application is primarily used and what types of queries are primarily used.

Comment: Thank for the tips I added some more context about my queries.